# Why does MinGW 4.8 not treat ex.what() as virtual?

Tags: c++, qt, exception, mingw

I'm using Qt Creator 3.0.1 with MinGW 4.8 32-bit as the compiler.

When I put the following code into the very top of my `main()` function (before Qt does all its stuff), the output I get on the console is "std::exception", not "Whoops" as I would expect:

```
try {
    throw std::logic_error{"Whoops"};
}
catch (std::exception ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

I've also tried accessing `what()` through a pointer:

```
try {
    throw std::logic_error{"Whoops"};
}
catch (std::exception ex) {
    std::exception* ex2 = &ex;
    std::cout << ex2->what() << std::endl;
}
```

The exact same code compiled in VS2013 outputs "Whoops" as I would expect.

`std::exception::what()` is virtual, so why is this happening?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c. `ex` is a `std::exception`, both statically and dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chris said, you're [slicing the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). You can prevent this by catching a const reference instead ([demo](http://ideone.com/cGvjKE)):

```
try {
    throw std::logic_error{"Whoops"};
} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl; // Whoops
}
```

Comment: I just found that out after looking into the link @chris posted above. I'll accept in 7 minutes when SO lets me :)